# Linq query populate collection from three tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have the following three tables:

```
[SURVEY_QUESTIONS]
(
[QuestionId]
[SurveyId],
[Question],
[AnswerType] 
)

[SURVEY_ANSWERS]
(
[AnswerId],
[QuestionId],
[ResponseId],
[Answer]
)

[SURVEY_RESPONSES]
(
[ResponseId],
[SurveyId]
)
```

I need to populate the following object and I have the ResponseId.

```
public class SurveyResponse
{
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

I started writing this method which would return a collection of the SurveyResponse object, but am not sure how to finish or what would be the best method to return my collection

```
    public static List<SurveyResponse> GetSurveyResponse(int responseId)
    {
        using (CaseDatabaseEntities entities = BaseDAL.GetNewEntities())
        {
            SURVEY_RESPONSES sr = entities.SURVEY_RESPONSES
                                                    .Where(r => r.ResponseId == responseId).FirstOrDefault();

            var Answers = entities.SURVEY_ANSWERS.Where(a => a.ResponseId == responseId);
            var Questions = entities.SURVEY_QUESTIONS.Where(q => q.SurveyId == sr.SurveyId);

            List<SurveyResponse> surveyResp = new List<SurveyResponse>();
            foreach (var q in Questions)
            {

            }

            return surveyResp;

        }
    }
```

Comment: have a look into joins and/or navigation properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can best be done using joins in Linq. Assuming the column "ResponseId" in the answer table corresponds to the column "ResponseId" in the survey responses table you could do the following:

```
var responses = (from s in entities.SURVEY_RESPONSES 
                  join q in entities.SURVEY_QUESTIONS on s.SurveyId equals q.SurveyId
                  join a in entities.SURVEY_ANSWERS on s.ResponseId equals a.ResponseId
                  where s.ResponseId == responseId
                  select new {s.ResponseId, q.Question, a.Answer});

List<SurveyResponse> surveyResp = new List<SurveyResponse>();
foreach (var r in responses)
{
  SurveyResponse survey = new SurveyResponse();
  survey.ResponseId = r.ResponseId;
  survey.Question = r.Question;
  survey.Answer = r.Answer;
  surveyResp.Add(survey);
}

return surveyResp;
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick, but I had to narrow the results: where s.ResponseId == responseId && a.QuestionId == q.QuestionId

Comment: @GoGetSOme Glad I could help! Alternatively, for your join to the question table, I think you could do `join q in entities.SURVEY_QUESTIONS on new { s.SurveyId, a.QuestionId } equals new{ q.SurveyId, q.QuestionId }` and place the join to the question table below the join to the answer table.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
public static List<SurveyResponse> GetSurveyResponse(int responseId)
{
    using (CaseDatabaseEntities entities = BaseDAL.GetNewEntities())
    {
        SURVEY_RESPONSES sr = entities.SURVEY_RESPONSES
                                                .Where(r => r.ResponseId == responseId).FirstOrDefault();

        var Answers = entities.SURVEY_ANSWERS.Where(a => a.ResponseId == responseId).;
        var Questions = entities.SURVEY_QUESTIONS.Where(q => q.SurveyId == sr.SurveyId);

        var questionsWithAnswers = (from q in Questions
                    join a in Answers on q.QuestionId equals a.QuestionId
                    select new SurveyResponse(){ ResponseId = a.responseId, Question = q.Question, Answer = a.Answer}).ToList()

        return questionsWithAnswers;

    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code.